# JSON API prevent circular relationships from being included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

I have the following model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
   def overlapping_tasks
     # call a query to return the list of overlapping_tasks of type Task based on dates
  end
end

class TaskSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes \
    :name

    has_many :overlapping_tasks, serializer: TaskSerializer
end
```

The JSON API is called with the following fields and include.

```
/tasks/1/fields[tasks]=name,overlapping_tasks,&include=overlapping_tasks

{ 
  data: 
  {"id"=>"1",
   "type"=>"tasks",
   "attributes"=>
    {
     "name"=>"Task 1",
     "start_date"=>"2012-01-01"
     "end_date"=>"2012-12-12",
    },
   "relationships"=>
    {"overlapping_tasks"=>
      {"data"=>[{"id"=>"2", "type"=>"tasks"}]}},
   "links"=>{"self"=>"/tasks/1"}}
  },
  "included": 
  { 
     [{"id"=>"2",
    "type"=>"tasks",
    "attributes"=>
       {"name"=>"Task 2",
        "start_date"=>"2012-01-01",
         "end_date"=>"2012-12-12",
      },
      "relationships"=>
          {"overlapping_tasks"=>
              {"data"=>[{"id"=>"1", "type"=>"tasks"}]}},
      "links"=>{"self"=>"/tasks/2"}}]
  }
}
```

The problem I have is in the included block, it also returns relationships for the overlapping_tasks of the overlapped task itself.  And ideally, I would only care about the overlap of the resource I am getting and want to just make one query for it (and skip the query for the overlap of the overlap).

In the fields[tasks], I specify that for the type tasks, we will return overlapping_tasks, so that's causing the task in the included block to also return overlapping_tasks.  Is there a way in the json-api spec to scope the resource of the included block if its of the same resource type as the data block?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "json-api spec"? This document https://jsonapi.org/format/ ?

Comment: What library are you using? There are [quite a few server-side libraries for ruby on rails](https://jsonapi.org/implementations/#server-libraries-ruby) and controlling the way [relationships are referenced](https://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-relationships) is most likely different for each of them.

Comment: @igneus.  Yes, by json-api spec, I meant https://jsonapi.org/format/.

Comment: @jelhan, At the moment, we are on ActiveModel::Serializers which is outdated, but looking to move maybe to jsonapi_resources or fast_jsonapi.